# How to stop prettier from putting my deconstructed code onto new lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, prettier

I am been pulling out my hair trying to turn this rule off, but I cannot.

[image]

### Before

```
const { data: { allModels = [] }, refetch } = useQuery(MODELS)
```

### After

```
  const {
    data: { allModels = [] },
    refetch
  } = useQuery(MODELS)
```

### .prettierrc

// I actually don't use all these rules, but I wanted to turn off as much as I could to test it.

```
{
  "printWidth":240,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": false,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "proseWrap": "never",
  "insertPragma": true,
  "quoteProps": "consistent",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

Worth noting I am using prettier in conjunction with eslint. But this particular rule is coming from prettier as seen in the print screen.

Comment: If you want to make decisions about how your code is laid out, prettier probably isn't the tool for you.

Comment: The whole idea of using prettier is not caring about how it formats the code.

Comment: Heh thanks guys, for both your input. Fundamentally I love prettier, this is a new rule introduced at once point in v1's life cycle. I like prettier... but hate this rule, hence... I'd love to veto lol

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: Cheers Dan, however I'd like to only remove this rule. Would you know how to control it?